# Ubuntu 12.10 x64 Doesn't detect RAM properly

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, ram

I have 6 GB installed, which as a 64-bit OS, it should see, but it only sees 3.5 GB! How do I remedy this?

Output as requested:

```
seann@seann:~$ dmidecode --type memory | grep -E "(Size|Maximum.Capacity)"
    Maximum Capacity: 4 GB
    Size: 2048 MB
    Size: 1024 MB
    Size: 2048 MB
    Size: 1024 MB

seann@seann:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3513       3328        185          0        373       2083

-/+ buffers/cache:        870       2642

Swap:         3907          4       3903
```

Comment: The whole point in switching to an x64 OS was to be able to use the full 6GB!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We'll need more information to be able to answer your question. Please provide the output of `sudo dmidecode --type memory | grep -E "(Size|Maximum.Capacity)"` and `free -m` run from the terminal. Please **edit** your question to include this.

Comment: Does your motherboard support more than 4 GB of ram?

Comment: Yes. When I boot into the BIOS it shows all 6 GB installed.

Comment: @Seann Your mainboard may support this memory configuration, but it's not showing it to the OS: `Maximum Capacity: 4 GB`. My best bet: in your BIOS there's an option to limit the amount of memory displayed to your OS for compatibility reasons. Disable that.

Comment: It is disabled. If enabled, it reports 256 MB to facilitate the smoothing-over of OS installation issues.

Comment: @gertvdijk It sounds like you may be able to post an answer.

Comment: @gertvdijk - Seems it's a BIOS limitation then, and I'm just stuck with it? Unless there's a BIOS update... Should have Googled that first I guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limitation of the BIOS. Though it reports 6 GB installed, only 4 can be used. Dell does have a flash available but it's unclear as to weather or not it addresses the upper-limit issue described here. Still waiting for Dell to get back to me.